# YouTube video crashes only when paused when a using headset, while in Firefox

Tags: firefox, audio, video, youtube

I have a [Logitech G35](http://gaming.logitech.com/en-us/product/g35-7-1-surround-sound-gaming-headset) headset, as well as a [Logitech Z5500](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002WPSBC) 5.1 surround system. I switch between these depending on need. For example the speakers for music, the headset for gaming.

Now, sometimes I like to watch YouTube videos trough the headset, and thus I switch to that. Here is where the problem comes: If I use my speakers, I can pause the video and leave it for ages, unpausing it will go right back to where I left off. But if I use the headset, and leave for only a minute, I have to reload the video because if I unpause it then it says “an error has occurred…” The issue only seems to happen in YouTube, other sites like twitch and err… uh… *cough* You know… Work fine.

I tested in Chrome, works fine, Internet Explorer I never touch so don’t bother. Updating Flash and Firefox yield no help. Reinstall of the browser hasn’t done anything either.

If it’s worth anything at all, here are the PC specs:

- Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit.
- 16 GB RAM.
- 2x Asus 760 cards (SLI).
- 2x SSD's HyperX ~250 GB.
- P8Z68-V PRO GEN3 Motherboard.
- Intel Core i7-3770 (not over-clocked).
- 2 HDD’s for file storage, no drivers or crucial software installed.

I have no idea where to even start now after what I have tried.

Comment: Have you tried in IE and Chrome?.

Comment: I went ahead and tested IE too, already stated I've tested chrome. Works flawlessly there. No add-ons that should do anything by sound. Only add-on that could remotely affect videos are Adblock plus, but I've used that for ages, never had issues with it before. And yes, have tried to disable that, no dice...

Comment: (1) Does right-clicking the video in FF give "About flash" ? If yes, try disabling all FF plugins except Flash, (2) Try changing the DNS servers to 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4, (3) Check computer date/time.

Comment: @Sharain What does [this page](https://www.youtube.com/html5) report about your web browser's HTML5 playback capability?

Comment: @Vinayak Please make an answer with your suggestion so I can properly credit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **[@harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc)** mentioned [in an earlier comment](https://superuser.com/questions/890843/youtube-video-crashes-only-when-paused-when-a-using-headset-while-in-firefox?noredirect=1#comment1195943_893586), the problem might lie with Flash and/or other plug-ins that may have malfunctioned.

As a temporary workaround, you can force YouTube to use the HTML5 player for playing back videos by visiting [this link](https://www.youtube.com/html5) and clicking on the **Request the HTML5 player** button.

[image: force HTML5 player for YouTube]

Comment: I am not sure if it's actually flash per se, or a combo of flash, firefox and my headset. Nevertheless, this answer describes the proper solution. Switching to HTML5 did the job. Now, let us all hope that we can finally kill flash once and for all, so HTML5 can grow as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Just to rule out an add-on issue, hold the SHIFT key when starting Firfox and choose to open FF in safe mode (this temperaraly disables addons). If the problem persists, it's not an add-on issue. Try this:

1. Make sure the headset is plugged into the green jack and not the microphone jack.
2. Install sound card drivers from your sound card company instead of using the Microsoft High Definition Audio drivers. (Has helped many).
3. Try to disable jack detection in Windows.
4. You can actually TRY to install a Youtube addon that might solve this. For example https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/youtube-high-definition/ or others.

Comment: It's an USB headset, and drivers for it is installed. Starting in safemode did not help.